# Image doesn't appear during debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, image

Following problem:
I just have an Image box on my window with following XAML Code:

```
<Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="261,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Stretch="Fill" IsHitTestVisible="True" Source="Resources/Jellyfish.jpg"/>
```

There are no errors and the image is shown in editing mode:
[Screenshot 1](http://img4.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/image1e67kcuxyv0.png)

But when I debug the program, the Image doesn't appear :(
[Screenshot 2](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/image2l67zr9mnj4.png)

Does anybody see a mistake?

Regards
MightyM

Comment: There is not error. Could you please upload your project somewhere and give us link.

Comment: "Resources/Jellyfish.jpg" --> Is it present in the Debug config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is

1. Ensure the your project has a folder called `Resources`
2. Your `Resources` folder has a file called jellyfish.jpg
3. The properties window of `JellyFish.jpg` shows the the Build Action is set to "Resource"

**3** will ensure that the **JellyFish.jpg** is embedded into your assembly as a resource stream. If you don't want an embedded resource you can look at [PACK URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) for your other choices